# android:imeOptions="actionNext" is working great, but screen is scrolling to top

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout, and want to get good navigation with "Next" Button.

All is working, but in field "et_numero", cursor focus to next field, this is ok, but screen scroll to top, I have no clue why!

Any help will be apreciated!

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_addpdv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


        <!-- Aqui empieza el formulario -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_pdv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pdv_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/pdv_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_dueno" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_dueno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_dueno"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/nombre_dueno"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_proyectos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_calle"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_calle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_calle"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/calle2"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_numero"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_colonia"
                android:layout_weight="0.8">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_numero"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/numero"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="number" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_colonia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_colonia"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/colonia2"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sp_ciudades"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:padding="20dp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_cp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"

                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_cp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/cp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="5"

                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_tel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"

                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_tel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/telefono2"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="phone"

                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_next1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_addpdv1"
        android:background="@drawable/button_azul_states"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/siguiente"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you looked into adding `android:nextFocus*` attributes to your input fields? You may try to set those to field itself to prevent transfer of focus entirely.

Comment: it's not working :( I tried with                         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_colonia"
but nothing changes

Comment: How do you format code in comments?